# if webdriver doesn't find an element then why not failing and quit the browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

webdriver script is need to be closed if an element not find, my script is looking for an element but it is not exist on the webpage.

But my script is not stops the execution and quit the browser.

Instead of stops running, continuously waiting form long time, it is a miracle.

Execution needs to stop and Browser needs to close this is what i am expecting.

Comment: @AfterClass
 public void endup() {
  driver.close();
  driver.quit();
 }
this is not executing because waiting for an element continuously

Comment: please provide more details. add some code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Please use try catch block. catch the NoSuchElementException and in catch block use driver.quit() method.

Comment: try{
   webelement_ds_NewD1.click();
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
          driver.quit();
        }
not worked for me, already tried with it. Run in debug mode also but executed still click() in try, cursor doesn't came to catch()

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem before, in my case changing:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("")
```

to

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("")
```

when you use "elements" it can return empty object however if you use "element" and the object is not found it will raise NoSuchElementException